# Deadlock using linq to sql select

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq-to-sql, azure-sql-database

I'm using linq to sql and running a direct SQL query - select statement - which queries a XML column using (XQuery). Multiple such queries are run in parallel and I'm getting deadlock exception.

Does select acquire some sort of lock when running? There are also updates happening in parallel with Serializable isolation level.

Any pointers how to get this problem resolved could be helpful. How do I specify NOLOCK in Linq To SQL?

Comment: are you *just* running queries? is any code doing an update? it is very unusual to get a deadlock just from queries

Answer (score 3):

I checked it on [Scott Hanselman's](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GettingLINQToSQLAndLINQToEntitiesToUseNOLOCK.aspx) Blog post. An example to try it like this

```
ProductsNewViewData viewData = new ProductsNewViewData();
using (var t = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required,
new TransactionOptions { 
    IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted 
}))
{
  viewData.Suppliers = northwind.Suppliers.ToList();
  viewData.Categories = northwind.Categories.ToList();
}
```

Hope its helpful for you. read it more on his blog post.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you getting a deadlock? SELECT on its own cannot deadlock with another SELECT. There must be more happening. [Capture the deadlock XML graph](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190465.aspx) and post it here so we can help you analyze it. Once we have the deadlock understanding we can recommend a solution, which is almost always a required index which you're missing.

Do **NOT** enable dirty reads (NOLOCK hints or read uncommitted isolation level), that is not the right approach. [Dirty reads are inconsistent reads](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2007/02/01/previously-committed-rows-might-be-missed-if-nolock-hint-is-used.aspx) and return *incorrect* data. If needed, [row versioning-based reads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177404%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) may be required, that's [how this very site](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/08/deadlocked.html) once solved it's issues.

Comment: Sorry, I'll update the question. There are also updates happening in parallel with Serializable isolation level.

Comment: The reads/Selects are running under Read Committed Snapshot Isolation Level.

Comment: I say that coz the SQL Server instance is SQL Azure, whose default isolation level is Read Committed Snapshot